# OScommerce How To Put Class in oscommerce function tep_draw_radio_field

Tags: class, oscommerce

This is the code:
echo tep_draw_radio_field('payment', $selection[$i]['id']);

and I want to put class on the tep_draw_radio_field

So the output would be:
<input type="radio" name="payment" value="cod" class="css-checkbox">

Answer (score 2):

The `tep_draw_radio_field` function accepts additional parameters that allow you to specify additional element attributes. To add a class using your example, you would call the function with the following parameters:

`echo tep_draw_radio_field('payment', $selection[$i]['id'], false, 'class="css-checkbox"');`

Note: the second parameter is a boolean that specifies whether the radio is selected or not.